# twig call macro in different folder

Tags: theming

i build a macro that contains a function. The function basically crop a text without catting words. My problem is how to call that twig macro if it is in different folder. if it is i same folder its easy. i just import the twig name. {% import 'croptext.twig' as cropText %}
But since this file contains a useful function all templates will call it so its better to put it in special folder like "tool" or "filter". But i still have any way to call it any help ?

```
{% macro crop_text(text, len) %}
  {% if text | length < len %}
    {{ text }}
  {% else %}
    {% set break = false %}
    {% set croppedParagraph = '' %}
    {% set paragraph = text | split(' ') %}
    {% set totalLength = 0 %}
    {% for word in paragraph  if not break %}
        {% if totalLength >= len %}
          {% set break = true %}
        {% else %}
          {% set totalLength = totalLength + 1 +  word | length %}
          {% set croppedParagraph = croppedParagraph ~ ' ' ~  word %}
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ croppedParagraph ~ ' ...' }}
 {% endif %}
```

{% endmacro %}

The function is working. I think its better to share more code to have a better idea about what i am doing. this is my project structure.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the macro by:

1. In the same twig Using `_self`:
   From Documentation:

   > It's possible to place the macro within the same twig from which you call it. The _self context is used in this case...

`{{ _self.crop_text(text, len) }}`

2. From External File using `import` :
   Like the following:
   Just move your `croptext.twig` into `yourtheme/templates` folder and then you can use the following call in any twig:

`{% import '@yourtheme/croptext.twig' as cropText %}`

For more information take a look at [Macros in Twig Templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/macros-in-twig-templates) documentation.

Comment: you can also do it the drupal 8 module way .. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PeAfExNSDk

Comment: thanks @berramou can i replaced to tool to better structure folder ? since this function its not really html template but a function that process a text ?

Comment: Taggart, i am decoupled from drupal as FE i have only twig. and local server form pattern-lab to render pages locally.